# Android Studio: can't see decompiled code from library

Tags: android

[image: I enter the library source the method is compiled code]

I don't know what I set. Android Studio I can see source before. But now each library the method is show "compiled code".

I try the method clean the dependencies. Attach the jar source. But it does not work.

How can I see the source in the library file?

Answer (score 2):

go to file > settings > plugins  search for Java Bytecode Decompiler and enable that plugin. it will fix your issue.